How to interlinked child automation projects to create one single parent project to run e2e test case
We are having 3 projects, let's call it A, B and C
All the 3 projects having different teams working on creating automated test cases. But these 3 projects are combined to create one project
I need to create one e2e framework to link all these 3 projects together so that methods and tests can be utilised to create one e2e test case
I know we can create jars of these 3 projects and import in my e2e framework but how?

Why do you have three separate projects if they need to come together to create one project? Why not just combine them into a single project and run your e2e scenarios from there?

These 3 projects are already created in the past and combining them into one project would be a tedeous task that's the reason we thought to write an integration layer

Are you using the page object model? How many tests are in each project?

If it were me, I would combine the three projects together into a single project. I think that makes the most sense if you want all three to work together.
I would organize the project like the below,
MainProject
\Common - Methods, things that are consistent among the three projects... maybe Util functions that process DateTime, strings, etc. that would be useful in all three projects.
\PageObjects - This is assuming that you are using the page object model, and if you aren't ... you should be. All page objects go in the folders below, broken down by project.
..\ProjectA
..\ProjectB
..\ProjectC
\Tests - All tests go in the folders below, broken down by project.
..\ProjectA
..\ProjectB
..\ProjectC

Once you get everything in this structure, you'll have to remap any page object, etc. references but hopefully your IDE will do most of the heavy lifting.
This should be good for a quick v1.0 and shouldn't take that long. Once you get this done, you can go about the harder work of making everything consistent. Things like...

Don't have 3 methods to do the same thing but slightly different. Write one final version of the method and then have all tests use it.
Consistency in page object model. I've seen a lot of page objects that aren't proper page objects. Get all of that sorted out and updated throughout the project. You're probably going to have to write a document outlining how a page object should be written, etc. so everyone will have a reference and do it consistently.
Consistency in tests. With proper page objects and good naming, each test should almost be human readable. You will probably need another document here to outline how tests should be written as a reference. You will need to decide things like... Where do we get test data from? How do we get test data? Asserts should all be in tests, not page objects, etc.

There are likely other documents that will be helpful... a style guide, coding conventions, etc.
Once all of this is done, it will be much easier going forward. It will become harder and harder to tell which person wrote which code... which is the ideal.
